# c# method chain vs linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, method-chaining

I wrote a query in method chain:

```
var query = finnEntities.FINN_TRANSACTION_VIEW.Where(
        x => x.CREDIT_ID == model.CodeId 
        || x.DEBTOR_ID == model.CodeId 
        && (x.TRANSACTION_DATE>= model.DateTimeFrom.Date 
            && x.TRANSACTION_DATE <= model.DateTimeTo.Date) 
        && x.CURRENCY_TYPE_ID == model.CurrencyId);
```

and I wrote the same query using linq expression:

```
var queryTransaction = 
    from t in finnEntities.FINN_TRANSACTION_VIEW
    where (t.CREDIT_ID == model.CodeId 
        || t.DEBTOR_ID == model.CodeId) 
        && (t.TRANSACTION_DATE >= model.DateTimeFrom 
            && t.TRANSACTION_DATE <= model.DateTimeTo) 
        && t.CURRENCY_TYPE_ID == model.CurrencyId
    select new { t };
```

but they have different output and the second one return correct result

Comment: You didn't write the same query - as well as the where clause being different, your query expression is using a projection to an anonymous type, for no obvious reason.

Comment: And whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the two queries you will see that you have

1. `()` around `t.CREDIT_ID == model.CodeId || t.DEBTOR_ID == model.CodeId` in the second query and you don't have them in the first. That changes the order of operations in your where-clause.
2. added `.Date` in the first, which truncates to the day, but not to the second.

Assuming the second query really is returning the right result, you can change the first to:

```
var query = finnEntities.FINN_TRANSACTION_VIEW.Where(x =>
    (x.CREDIT_ID == model.CodeId || x.DEBTOR_ID == model.CodeId)
    && x.TRANSACTION_DATE>= model.DateTimeFrom
    && x.TRANSACTION_DATE <= model.DateTimeTo
    && x.CURRENCY_TYPE_ID == model.CurrencyId);
```

In the above, I also dropped the redundant `()` around the anded portions of the query.

Comment: you give the correct I forgot to put braces around date comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are different. Just compare how you wrote the conditions and you should notice the bracket and date-difference.

```
x.CREDIT_ID == model.CodeId || x.DEBTOR_ID == model.CodeId && (x.TRANSACTION_DATE>= model.DateTimeFrom.Date && x.TRANSACTION_DATE <= model.DateTimeTo.Date) && x.CURRENCY_TYPE_ID == model.CurrencyId


(t.CREDIT_ID == model.CodeId || t.DEBTOR_ID == model.CodeId) && (t.TRANSACTION_DATE >= model.DateTimeFrom && t.TRANSACTION_DATE <= model.DateTimeTo) && t.CURRENCY_TYPE_ID == model.CurrencyId
```

Also it is a good idea (for readability) to put more complex conditions into a function like this:

```
bool _iHaveAMeaningfulName(Model model, WhatEver t)
{
    return (t.CREDIT_ID == model.CodeId || t.DEBTOR_ID == model.CodeId) && 
           (t.TRANSACTION_DATE >= model.DateTimeFrom && t.TRANSACTION_DATE <= model.DateTimeTo) && 
            t.CURRENCY_TYPE_ID == model.CurrencyId
}
```

Then you can reuse it more easily and also compare Linq-Queries with method chains way better:

```
// Method-Chain
finnEntities.FINN_TRANSACTION_VIEW.Where(t => _iHaveAMeaningfulName(model,t));

// query
from f in finnEntities.FINN_TRANSACTION_VIEW
where _iHaveAMeaningfulName(f,model)
select new { f }; // this returns an annonymous type
```

You should also notice that your query return an annonymous type because you wrote:

```
select new { f };
```

in order to be equivalent to the method chain you need to remove the new { }

```
select f;
```

Comment: Actually in this case the brackets will not effect the logic.  As Habib pointed out the OP is comparing the dates differently.

Comment: I cannot agree on that 'a or b and c' is equivalent to '(a or b) and c'